# Best way to get free driving instructions

Tags: java, maps, driving-directions

Is there a simple way to get driving instructions?

Something like: I call "http://someservice/?start=NYC&target=Washington" and then the service returns a XML file containing routing information?

Has anybody ever tried to access such a web-based service from a standalone desktop application?

Any help would really be appreciated!

Update: Thanks for the hints, but unfortunately I can't run JavaScript. Is there still a possibility to receive driving instructions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you looked at the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/)?

Also see how to [Add Google Maps’ Directions to Your Site](http://www.malevolent.com/weblog/archive/2005/05/01/add-google-maps/).

Answer (score 3):

[Google maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/index.html).

An example from the [Directions doc](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/services.html#LoadingDirections):

```
// Create a directions object and register a map and DIV to hold the 
// resulting computed directions

var map;
var directionsPanel;
var directions;

function initialize() {
  map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
  directionsPanel = document.getElementById("my_textual_div");
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng(49.496675,-102.65625), 3);
  directions = new GDirections(map, directionsPanel);
  directions.load("from: 500 Memorial Drive, Cambridge, MA to: 4 Yawkey Way, Boston, MA 02215 (Fenway Park)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application, it may not yet be a viable option, but you might want to look at the various routing offerings using [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org) data.  The [routing wiki page](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) provides more information on the various projects.